# Oracle Database 19c Wallet for OTW Encryption Will Not Enter Ready State

Tags: oracle, certificate, wallet

I create a wallet, generate the request, receive a p7b file, import the p7b into the wallet, but the cert will not enter the "Ready" state.  When viewed in Oracle Wallet Manager the Certificate is listed as "Requested". I can see the root certificate and requested machine cert so the cert path appears complete.  What am I missing?  Listed below are the commands that I'm using.

```
REM Create Wallet
orapki wallet create -wallet D:\mypath -auto_login -pwd mypass

REM Generate CSR
orapki wallet add -wallet D:\mypath -pwd mypass -dn "CN=myserver.one.two.three,OU=MyOu,O=MyComp,L=MyCity,ST=MyState,C=US" -keysize 4096 -sign_alg sha256 -addext_san DNS:myserver.one.two.three

REM Export CSR to file
orapki wallet export -wallet D:\mypath -pwd mypass -dn "CN=myserver.one.two.three,OU=MyOu,O=MyComp,L=MyCity,ST=MyState,C=US" -request D:\certs\mycsr.csr

REM import the received p7b file into the wallet
orapki wallet add -wallet D:\mypath -trusted_cert -cert "D:\mypath\myp7b.p7b" -pwd mypass
```

I expect that after importing the p7b file the cert will enter the ready state.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The cert needs to be added as trusted cert (which I initially did) and then added as a user cert via this command:

orapki wallet add -wallet D:\mypath -user_cert -cert Server.cer -pwd mypass